# Angular 2 custom validator runs two times

Tags: validation, angular

I following stripped code for debugging purposes. The emailForCloudUserValidator runs two times on single NgOnInit run logging two messages to console.

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.contactControlGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    email:[this.contact.email, this.emailForCloudUserValidator]
  });
  this.formControls = this.contactControlGroup.controls;
}

private emailForCloudUserValidator(control: Control) :  { [s: string]: boolean }{
  if(!control.value){
    console.log("email value is null");
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: can't reproduce your issue. can you possibly provide a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5) ?

Answer (score 2):

Calling `enableProdMode()` before `bootstrap()` should fix it:

```
import {enableProdMode} from "angular2/core";

enableProdMode();
```

By default Angular2 runs in `devMode` where change detection always runs twice to check for model instabilities that indicate a bug in your application (which produces the error message `Expression 'xxxx' was changed after it was checked`)

Comment: @mishap then I guess this is an initial run for `null` and then again when the value changes to `this.contact.email`

Comment: @mishap. I havent tried it yet. So cant say anything. I said thanks because I didnt know about this information.